# Condition for a formal power series to be a Laurent polynomial

Tags: laurent-series, formal-power-series

Let $s(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb C [[x_1, x_2]] [x_1^{-1},x_2^{-1}]$ with all coefficients equal to one or zero. For example
$$ s(x_1,x_2)=\frac1{(1-x_1)(1-x_2)}$$
Now let
$$ t(x_1,x_2) = \sum_{i=1}^n s(x_1^{a_i} x_2^{b_i},x_1^{c_i} x_2^{d_i})$$
where $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i \in \mathbb Z$ for all $i$,
and $a_i b_i \neq 0 \neq c_i d_i$.
For example
$$t(x_1,x_2)=\frac1{(1-x_1)(1-x_2)} +\frac1{(1-x_1^{-1})(1-x_1^{-1} x_2)}$$

Is it true that if $\lim_{x_1,x_2\to1} t(x_1,x_2)$ is finite, then $t(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb C [x_1^\pm, x_2^\pm]$?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Maybe you meant : let $f(x_1,x_2) = \sum_{i,j \ge -N} a_{i,j} x_1^i x_2^j \in \Bbb{C}[[x_1,x_2]][x_1^{-1},x_2^{-1}]$ such that all $a_{i,j} \in 0,1$, thus $f$ is also an analytic function on $0<|x_1|<1,0<|x_2|< 1$, if $f$ is bounded as $x_1,x_2\to 1^-$ are there only finitely many non-zero $a_{i,j}$ ? The answer is clearly yes.

Comment: @reuns I mean $s \in \mathbb C[[x_1,x_1^{-1},x_2,x_2^{-1}]]$, and such that all $a_{i,j}$ are zero or one.

Comment: No you don't mean that because $\Bbb{C}[[x,x^{-1}]]$ isn't a ring, it is different if you restrict to the series that converge in some neighborhood of $0$ (the ring of analytic functions) and if all the coefficients are 0 or 1 then the convergence means there are finitely many positive or negative coefficients which reduces to my 1st comment.

Comment: @reuns I see, perhaps you're right, but then is e.g. $\frac{1}{1-x_1/x_2}$ an element of $\mathbb C [[x_1,x_2]] [x_1^{-1},x_2^{-1}]$?

Comment: @reuns I tried to clarify my question